# Не работает конструктор в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Добрый день! Есть стандартный класс для авторизации User. В нём мне надо сделать так, чтобы данные о пользователях брались из баз данных. Прописал следующий код:

```
    use app\models\GetUsers;

    class User extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements 
    \yii\web\IdentityInterface
   {
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $authKey;
public $accessToken;
//public $usersArray = GetUsers::getUsersArray();

private static $users; //= User::$usersArray;

public function __construct(){
    User::$users = GetUsers::getUsersArray();
    var_dump(User::$users);

}
```

Здесь я написал конструктор, чтобы свойству $users присваивался массив, который берётся из отдельной модели GetUsers. Далее ничего не менял. В результате выдаётся ошибка **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**. Попробовал вывести свойство $users через var_dump - пишет NULL, то есть **конструктор не работает**, следовательно, пустое свойство отдаётся foreach - в результате ошибка. При этом массив из модели GetUsers однозначно получается (Проверял через var_dump). Где ошибка? Я только начинаю изучать yii2, поэтому прошу не кидать помидоры.

Comment: `Попробовал вывести свойство $users через var_dump - пишет NULL` ............`При этом массив из модели GetUsers однозначно получается (Проверял через var_dump)` - так NULL или "однозначно получается"?

Comment: @Алексей, Массив получается из модели, но его значение не присваивается свойству $users, так как не работает конструктор. А почему - вот в том-то и вопрос.

Comment: А вы где-то пишите `new User()` ?

Comment: А, то есть конструктор работает только при создании объектов класса? Спасибо, не знал. Как-то проскочил этот момент

Comment: А вы думали когда он работает? О_о  :)

Comment: Всё заработало. Большое спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php